# NUMBERS TO WORDS using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, type-conversion, switch-statement, string-conversion

NUMBER TO WORDS
convert number to word in javaScript displayed take output from user using HTML page
easy and simple using for and switch statement

Comment: Hi Radheesh! Please simplify your question to be better understood. That way, it will be easier to provide answers for! 
Be precise on what is the error/requirement/question. We're happy to help! :)

Comment: Read [ask], then [edit] with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <br><br>
    <h1>NUMBER TO WORDS</h1>
    <input type="5ber" id="nm1" placeholder="number"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="To Words" id="optin" onclick="pldstrng()">
    <p id="value" style="color: blueviolet;"></p>

    <script>
        function pldstrng() {
            var k = document.getElementById("nm1").value
            var a = String(k)
            for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                switch (a[i]) {
                    case "1":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="one"+" " 
                        break
                    case "2":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="two"+" "
                        break
                    case "3":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="three"+" "
                        break
                    case "4":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="four"+" "
                        break
                    case "5":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="five"+" "
                        break
                    case "6":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="six"+" "
                        break
                    case "7":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="siven"+" "
                        break
                    case "8":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="eight"+" "
                        break
                    case "9":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="nine"+" "
                        break
                    case "0":
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML+="zero"+" "
                        break
                    default :
                        document.getElementById("value").innerHTML="enter a number / digit"+" "    
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help you , i dont think there is a more straight forward way than this.

```
var num = "zero one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen".split(" ");
var tens = "twenty thirty forty fifty sixty seventy eighty ninety".split(" ");

function number2words(n){
    if (n < 20) return num[n];
    var digit = n%10;
    if (n < 100) return tens[~~(n/10)-2] + (digit? "-" + num[digit]: "");
    if (n < 1000) return num[~~(n/100)] +" hundred" + (n%100 == 0? "": " and " + number2words(n%100));
    return number2words(~~(n/1000)) + " thousand" + (n%1000 != 0? " " + number2words(n%1000): "");
}
```

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/convert+number+to+words+in+javascript